# Duplicate user's permissions across farm in SP2010

Tags: 2010, permissions

I have just taken over as developer of a Sharepoint farm with multiple site collections. I keep having to assign myself the relevant permissions that my predecessor had across various areas.

Is there any way I can duplicate his permissions to myself across the whole farm to save me having to keep switching user?

Naturally, I will create a group for Global Administrators so that my successor won't have this issue!

Comment: You can use the powershell script in this blog : http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2009/04/24/the-power-of-powershell-and-sharepoint-enumerating-sharepoint-permissions-and.aspx to get the previous user permission and then you can set you user permission by modifiying this script to add your self as a user

Comment: Thanks - sounds possible but I am a total newbie to both Sharepoint and .NET scripting and so I would have no idea how to adapt it to add myself the permissions (and would therefore have to return here to ask further questions!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can add your self as Site collection admin to all site collection. you can use a PS for that. by this way you have access to all the Site collections and you dont need to worry about the old user logins.

you can use this script :

http://sharepointryan.com/2011/05/23/add-a-site-collection-administrator-to-all-sites-in-a-web-application/